# setup: The program 'pg_config' is required but it could not be found

Tags: postgresql, haskell-stack, nixos

On nixos, when attempting to build my project with `$ stack --nix build`, I run into the following error.

```
$ stack --nix build

...

Linking /run/user/1000/stack25943/postgresql-libpq-0.9.2.0/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nix/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/setup ...
Configuring postgresql-libpq-0.9.2.0...
setup: The program 'pg_config' is required but it could not be found.
```

I have installed postgres following the [nixos manual](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#module-postgresql) and do have `pg_config` installed, as shown by

```
$ which pg_config
/run/current-system/sw/bin/pg_config
```

It appears that stack does not know this location of my pg_config.

**How do I proceed to get `$ stack --nix build` to succeed?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to add Nix packages to the nix-shell environment that it's building Haskell packages in.

In `stack.yaml`:

```
nix:
  packages: [postgresql]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're getting this on mac, run `brew install postgres` then `stack build`

Comment: And the bin should be added to shell path

Comment: The OP wants to use stack's integration with nix: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/nix_integration/. In other words, nix should manage all non-Haskell dependencies.